# Exception while accessing a method on web service

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I am writing a client application which would consume the webservice and should be able to get the data. Using the wsdl of the webservice I generated proxy classes in my client application. I followed the "Adding Service Reference" approach to generate proxies. Now, when I am trying to access the method on the webservice, I am getting this error: "neither UsernameToken nor Signature was provided". My first suspect was it needed the credentials and I tried to supply them in my code. But still I am seeing the issue. The reason I am providing the credentials in my code is because we have 2 web services one is QA and the other one is production. Their wsdl are same but the credentials are different, so I will be making the credentials configurable so that the end user can input it based on which ever web service they want to access.

Please let me know, if there is anything I am missing. Thanks

Here is my code (this is a small test snippet to test webservice calls):

```
GetApplicationServiceClient client= new GetApplicationServiceClient();          
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "userId";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";           
        int[] input= new int[3]{1,2,3};
        GetAppResponse response= new GetAppResponse();
       foreach (var item in input)
       {
         response = client.getAppById(item);
       }
```

Here is my config file:

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="GetApplicationServiceSoapBinding">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="GetApplicationServiceSoapBinding1" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://TestService.com/bo-service/v2/ws/get-application"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="GetApplicationServiceSoapBinding"
            contract="TestService.GetApplicationService" name="GetApplicationServicePort" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your web service offers Transport Security with Basic Authentication, try this

```
     ...
        <binding name="GetApplicationServiceSoapBinding">
            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
            </security>
        </binding>
     ...
```